# Conditional Import of .css theme file using React Hooks

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two theme files: light.css and dark.css. I want to switch between the two themes with the useState React Hook (or another method in a react functional components).

For example, I have this in my Navbar functional component:

```
import "./light.css"
```

So I want a mechanism to import (or rather switch) the two files using the hooks based on a user action by pressing a toggle or a button on the Navbar which would call a 'setTheme' and have that in a useEffect block.

Does that make sense? If yes, how do I do that? All the tutorials I can find are based on hardcoded css while in my situation I *must* use the two files mentioned above. thanks

Comment: read about css modules

Comment: How you recognize the current theme? I mean do you have any related `local state` for that?

Comment: @DennisVash you mean this? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/ Doesn't help, unfortunately. thanks.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani the users get for example the "light" theme by default, and then they should have the ability to switch to the "dark" with the toggle/button. The "how" is what i am asking for here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I basically used what I was suggesting in my question but with an extra twist:

I used those hooks: useState, useEffect and useContext

- the useState: to switch the values between dark and light.
- the useContext: to write in the localstorage the theme:  item (for persistence)
- the useEffect: to check the value from the local storage each time the theme value is changed + refresh the browser.

Not sure if it is the neatest solution, but it works and saves the user preference which is a plus for me.

Comment: Can you post a code example so we can understand?